# Selecting only first match with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

`document.querySelector("h2")` returns only the first element that matches that class selector.

Could this be done in CSS? It is not like doing: `h2:first-child` as this would select every `<h2>` that is the first element of its parent...

Take for example this:

```
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Sub</h2>
    <article>
        <h1>Title2</h1>
        <p>Blabla</p>
        <h2>Introduction</h2>
        <p>Blabla</p>
        <h2>Methods</h2>
        <h2>Conclusions</h2>
    </article>
    <footer>
        <h2>Bla</h2>
    </footer>
</body>
```

I know there are ways to select only that `<h2>` containing "Sub", but could I ask like in querySelector: get all of them and filter the first, the second or the third one...?

Comment: are you looking for this? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/

Comment: @JoelAlmeida nope, I'd like to pick the first one no matters the structure

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve but with only css it won't be possible, at least of what I'm aware of. What if you target only the first level after the body? `body > h2:first-of-type{}` ?

Comment: Can't be done with pure css